# How to replace special character in shell?

Tags: shell

I have a string:

```
sam1/0/2
```

I have to replace it using shell command to:

```
sam-1/0/2/4:4
```

Any help?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape those special characters while replacement with sed.

see below command

```
sed "s/sam1\/0\/2/sam-1\/0\/2\/4\:4/g" ---- g is for all occurrences on a line
sed "s/sam1\/0\/2/sam-1\/0\/2\/4\:4/"  ---- first occurrence on a line
```

Example,

```
[root@giam39 ~]# sed "s/sam1\/0\/2/sam-1\/0\/2\/4\:4/" file1.txt > file2.txt
[root@giam39 ~]# cat file1.txt
sam1/0/2
[root@giam39 ~]# cat file2.txt
sam-1/0/2/4:4
[root@giam39 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string="sam1/0/2"
echo "$string" | sed -e 's/1\/0\/2/-1\/0\/2\/4:4/g'
```

`sed` - stream editor for filtering and transforming text

with pipe ( `|` ) you can pass the output of `$string` to `sed`.
By using sed you can find a substring in a string with a specific pattern.

Structure: `sed -e 's/ugly/beautiful/g'`